# ¿Porqué no aparece el array en mi html si parece en la consola?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Metodo Get desde una WebApi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Html que segun deberia imprimir todo lo que tenga mi base de datos en este caso tiene 3 elementos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En consola se muestra lo que tiene mi base de datos si lo imprime en consola pero no se porque no sale en el html se muestra como vacio

Comment: Tendrías que utilizar `NgFor` en este caso, lectura recomendada: https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las reglas de la comunidad, por ejemplo, el código debe ir como texto en lugar de usar imágenes. Si no cambias esto, tu pregunta terminará cerrada.